# How to add tweet for particular user from rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using twitter gem.

```
Twitter.update("message") updates login who registered the app.
```

How to update a specific login ?

I have tried

```
 Twitter.user('some other user').update('message')
```

But it shows error.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to post a message to users account, we should have a valid oauth token and oauth token secret for the user. For this we need to prompt the user to sign in and we can get these two.

I used twitter_oauth gem for this purpose.

Reference: https://github.com/moomerman/twitter_oauth

Comment: Actually tweets for the login are saved in database.The tweets will be sent via cron.So i need to send tweets without browser redirect.Is it possible?

Comment: As I mentioned above we cannot post a tweet into twitter without having user Oauth secret and token. The possible option would be collect these two from user once by prompting user to sign in though oauth and save it in your database. Once we have these values we can post to twitter using cron.

Comment: Ok.+1 for your guidance.Thank you :)

Comment: I am trying twitter_oauth gem.Will accept your answer when stuff works